# Give access priviliges in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeigniter, I have function to restrict controller,

```
private function controllerAccess(){
    $sessionArray = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    if($sessionArray['type'] == 'ADMIN' || $sessionArray['type'] == 'SUPERVISOR'){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am preventing my index controller by doing this,

```
public function index(){
    $system = new SYSTEM();
    $this->controllerAccess() ? $this->dashboard() : $system->container('No Access');
}
```

The problem is, Do I need to do the same thing with each public method (controller)?
Because, by doing this: I can access child controllers. For example, I can not access index page for agent. but I can access: agent/dashboard, agent/validate, etc...

Is there any method to block entire controller?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue what you actually mean and I've been using CI for 2 years now. It might be me but..  You might want to use an authex library since you request the userdata in your controller, that's no good in my eyes.

You should be something like

```
$user = $this->authex->getSession();
```

And to check if the user is appropriate to view the page you just use this function

```
private function verifyUser() {
        $user = $this->authex->getSession();
        if ($user == null)
            redirect('hub/notauthorized/', 'refresh');
    }
```

and you call it in every public function where you want to check the user rights like this

```
$this->verifyUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

just run the function in the constructor of your controller, and then the function will run everytime your controller is hit

```
class YourController extends CI_Controller {
   public function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
        if(!$this->controllerAccess(){
            //you got a false so redirect or whatever you want to do on negative

        }
   }

   private function controllerAccess(){
        $sessionArray = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        if($sessionArray['type'] == 'ADMIN' || $sessionArray['type'] == 'SUPERVISOR'){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

   public function index(){
        $system = new SYSTEM();
        $this->controllerAccess() ? $this->dashboard() : $system->container('No Access');
    }
}
```